# Deserializing JSON to Java using GSON results in empty fields

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I use Gson to parse my JSON response from an API. But when I try to get the content it's empty.

My serialized class:

```
class Weather {
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("main")
@Expose
private String main;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("icon")
@Expose
private String icon;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getMain() {
    return main;
}

public void setMain(String main) {
    this.main = main;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

public void setIcon(String icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}
```

}

And my call:

```
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        Weather weather = gson.fromJson("{\"weather\":[{\"id\":800,\"main\":\"Clear\",\"description\":\"clear sky\",\"icon\":\"01n\"}]}", Weather.class);
        Log.i("[Weather]", "Weather: " + weather.getDescription());
```

Description and the others field are empty I don't understand why ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing along the full JSON, try to pass only what's inside the array associated with "weather", like this:

```
 Weather weather = gson.fromJson("{\"id\":800,\"main\":\"Clear\",\"description\":\"clear sky\",\"icon\":\"01n\"}", Weather.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You created model class a JSON array item, not for complete JSON object. Create a new serializable class for example WeatherObject as below

```
class WeatherObject {
@SerializedName("weather")
@Expose
private ArrayList<Weather> weather;
// getters and setters
}
```

Use this class in `gson.fromJson` method